# How do i get the native query generated by waterline in sails.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline

When using waterline as orm (default) in sails or as a standalone, is it possible to have access to the native query (according to the used adapter) generated by calling model methods?
Lets assume i have a User model, and that i call `.find` on it with no criteria.

```
User.find().then(function(users){
  // Is there a something like this?
  console.log(users._query); // If using mysql it logs... SELECT * from `user` 
})
```

Of course that this is a trivial example, but when we have complex chainings, it'll be really helpful to have access to it, so we can be sure our queries are constructed in a similar fashion to what we are expecting, and if not refactor them or use the method `.query` to manually construct our queries.

So, is this possible? Even in a hacky ugly way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd love to have this functionality too, but [it does not seem available](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/blob/master/lib/adapter.js#L29-L33).

However if you are using MySQL/MariaDB, there is [a hacky ugly way](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/blob/master/lib/adapter.js#L29-L33) indeed. Try this in your shell before launching your app:

```
export LOG_QUERIES=true
```

Comment: Too bad is not there yet, but hey great hack, it works.